# How to search MS SQL column in JSON array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have several columns in my database. In one of these columns is a JSON string like: fyvfvv.

```
[
  {
    "Value": "0000138010687",  
    "Name": "Code"
  }
]
```

I need to select those rows from the database, whose JSON is filled with the value of the mask `"0000****"`, or the value is greater than a certain number.
Can you tell me how to do it in the best way?

Comment: Have you had a look at `OPENJSON`? What have you tried? Why didn't it work.

Comment: Don't use such columns if you intend to query them. You can't use any indexes in a JSON query so you end up scanning the entire table. That's a bad JSON schema too, making querying with JSON functions a lot harder if not impossible - why not use `"Code":"0000138010687"` ?

Comment: If you change the JSON schema to the normal `{"key":"value"}` you'll be able to use `JSON_VALUE(field,'$.Code')` to get the code value. You'll also be able to create a computed *and* persisted field that can be indexed eg `ThatCode AS JSON_VALUE(field,'$.Code') PERSISTED`. Your query could become as simple as `WHERE ThatCode LIKE '0000%'` *and* take advantage of indexes.

Comment: `the value is greater than a certain number` that's another unusual requirement. Strings aren't numbers either in JSON or SQL. In JSON, `2` is a number but `"2"` is a string that's greater than `"0000138010687"` because strings are ordered alphabetically, and `"2"` comes after `"0"`. You can use `TRY_CAST` to try and parse the value into a number. `TRY_CAST` will return `NULL` if the cast fails. If the JSON string had a normal schema you could use `ThatCode_AsNumber AS TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE(field,'$.Code') as number(18,0)) PERSISTED`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is a legacy enterprise database with 10 years of history and it's not my place to change it. The column stores a lot of data in json form (I cut it down for example to understand the principle and redo it for myself) which is further used in many processes

Comment: That doesn't make it a good design. You'll have to explain what you actually want to do and what the actual data looks like. If there are multiple `name/value` pairs in the array you'll have to extract all of them and filter with `WHERE`. You won't be able to avoid the full table scan which means what you do will impact everyone using that table, as it will take a Shared lock on all rows, unless other conditions on indexed columns reduce the number of rows to scan

Comment: Zhorov's answer may be the only option. None of SQL Server's [JSON functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) allow filtering by content. You can write `JSON_VALUE(field,'$.Code')` to get the `Code` field but you can't use `JSON_VALUE(field,'$.Value','$.Name = "Code"'). To use `OPENJSON` in a computed column expression you'd have to create a function like the one [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544001/134204). This works because the column is persisted so the value only has to be calculated once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the json array contains one element only, then we can use `JSON_VALUE()` to get the element value by path :

```
select *
from (
  select *, 
    JSON_VALUE(JsonColumn, '$[0].Value') as theValue, 
    JSON_VALUE(JsonColumn, '$[0].Name') as theName
  from JsonTable
) as s
where theName = 'Code' and theValue like '0000%';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CwrBkjCV)

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the stored JSON with `OPENJSON()` and use the appropriate `WHERE` clause.

Data:

```
SELECT *
INTO JsonTable
FROM (VALUES
   ('[{"Value": "00001380", "Name": "Code"}]'),
   ('[{"Value": "0000138010688", "Name": "Code"}]'),
   ('[{"Value": "0000138010689", "Name": "Code"}]')
) v (JsonColumn)
```

Statement (to get the rows):

```
SELECT *
FROM JsonTable t
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonColumn) WITH (
      [Value] varchar(100) '$.Value',
      [Name] varchar(100) '$.Name'
   )
   WHERE [Value] LIKE '0000____'  
)
```

Statement (to get the rows and the parsed JSON):

```
SELECT *
FROM JsonTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JsonColumn) WITH (
   [Value] varchar(100) '$.Value',
   [Name] varchar(100) '$.Name'
) j
WHERE j.[Value] LIKE '0000____'
```

Both statements return the correct results, even if the parsed JSON array contains more than one item.